# Deploy Flask Microblog in private ec2 with private RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, private, subnet, vpc

for a project with AWS I am trying to install a microblog made with flask on an ec2.
The architecture, for now, consists of

1. A bastion host deployed in public subnet with ip.
2. An ec2 deployed in private subnet without ip.
3. A RDS (Mysql) deployed in private subnet without public access.
4. An EFS mounted on the ec2 of the private subnet.

All elements are in the same VPC.

The security groups are

1. Bastion Host - SSH(22) inbound rule from my ip
2. EC2 - SSH(22) inbound rule from bastion host and Mysql/Aurora(3306) inbound rule from RDS
3. RDS - Mysql/Aurora(3306) inbound rule from private EC2
4. EFS - NFS inbound rule (2049) from private EC2

I have accessed the bastion by ssh and from the bastion I have accessed the ec2 of the private subnet, I have installed the necessary packages for the application. I have created an .env with the RDS access data(DATABASE_URL=mysql+pymysql://db-user:db-password@db-host:db-port/db-
database) and tried to run `flask db upgrade`, but I get the errors I put below.
Is there something that I have missed or that is not configured like this? I am new to AWS.
Thanks!!!

```
[2024-02-21 16:35:56,754] INFO in __init__: Microblog startup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3282, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 449, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1263, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 712, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 282, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 390, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 674, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 901, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 896, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 643, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 954, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 772, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'db-final-database'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 1050, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 357, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_migrate/cli.py", line 150, in upgrade
    _upgrade(directory, revision, sql, tag, x_arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 111, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 200, in upgrade
    command.upgrade(config, revision, sql=sql, tag=tag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 403, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 583, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 95, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 113, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "migrations/env.py", line 94, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "migrations/env.py", line 76, in run_migrations_online
    connection = engine.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3258, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 147, in __init__
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2422, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3282, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 449, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1263, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 712, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 282, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 390, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 674, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 901, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 896, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 643, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 954, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 772, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database 'db-final-database'")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

I have tried this and it seems to connect but does not transmit data

```
$ nc -vz db-final-database.csfitfdo13cc.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
Ncat: Version 7.93 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 10.0.0.68:3306.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.04 seconds.
```

Comment: Is there a database actually named `db-final-database`? BTW you don't need to allow "Mysql/Aurora(3306) inbound rule from RDS" in the EC2 security group because Security Groups are stateful and RDS is not making any connections to EC2 (it's the other way around).

Comment: Yes, the database exists.
Thanks for the information on the security group, at first I did not have it set, but with the tests I have left it like that.
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: The error message strongly suggests there is no such database. A connectivity issue wouldn't cause that outcome afaik (it would be timeout or something more relevant). Note that the database name isn't necessarily the same as the RDS name.

Comment: Have you accessed the RDS instance from the bastion host? Or by using the `mysql` command from the private EC2 instance? You need to connect to RDS MySQL from one of those servers, and run the command `SHOW DATABASES;` and verify that the DB named `db-final-database` actually exists. The error message says it does not. As jarmod mentioned, just because the RDS server name is `db-final-database` doesn't mean there is a MySQL database schema created on that server with the name `db-final-database`.

Comment: Inside RDS I click on create database, "standard creation", choose the mysql engine and the free layer to deploy on a t2.micro. In Database Instance Identifier is where I put the name. I understand that this is the name of the database or is it the RDS instance?
Then I put user and password, I choose the option "Do not connect to an EC2 compute resource" I choose the same VPC and the subnet group I create. Public access "NO". I choose the security group and Password Authentication.
Is it correct that once deployed, the endpoint is the RDS and the name I chose is the database?

Comment: You created an [RDS DB Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.html) running MySQL. You didn't create a database. To do that, you connect a MySQL client to the RDS DB Instance and then use SQL (or other) to create one or more databases. The terminology here is confusing and inconsistent, it has to be said.

Comment: OMG, now it all makes sense. Thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The different uses of the term 'database' are the problem here. It's common for them to be confused.

You created an [RDS DB Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.html) running MySQL. That's an AWS resource. It's not a MySQL database.

You need to actually create a MySQL database. To do that, you connect a MySQL client to the RDS DB Instance and then use SQL (or other) to create one or more databases.